# Trying to add a 'tier' attribute to users (using devise). Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've generated a migration with the command:

```
rails generate migration add_tier_to_user tier:string
```

to add tiers for users, like 'admin' or 'student'.

After that, though, `db:rake` has stopped working and is returning an error.

The migration file:

```
class AddTierToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change 
    add_column :users, :tier, :string 
  end 
end
```

The error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

Comment: It's very difficult to help if you don't give us more information. For starters, show us the migration file and copy the error. For all I know, you ran the exact line you posted, and since table names are typically plural, rake couldn't find a `user` table on which to perform a migration.

Comment: class AddTierToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration

       def change
       add_column :users, :tier, :string

      end
    end


Uh, trying to get it appear going down in a list but doesn't seem to be doing that? Also the number of errors popping up after rake abort is quite a list. But I get errors like "ActiveRecord: :RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken".

I don't get it either.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error you're getting, I think this happened:

1. you created two or more `User` records with the same `email` value.
2. you generated the migration file.
3. you added a uniqueness validation for the `email` field.
4. you tried to run the migration.

If I am right, the problem is not caused by the migration *per se*, but by the fact that, when you load the Rails environment via `rake db:something`, a `User` is being created or updated automatically.

Comment: So I'm sort of half guessing what you're saying, but then what would be your suggestion in that case?

Comment: Add the logs/output of `rake db:migrate` to the question, please.